# How to upgrade mantis bug tracker database online?

Tags: mantis, tracker

Your database has not been created yet. Please create the database, then install the tables and data using the information above before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ftp/sftp/scp app like WinSCP to examine your directory. 
There's usually a readme file in the directory.
Read it and do what it says. It'll likely say to run a script, visit an admin page (and then remove it when you're done), etc..  Or it may say to create your database, and enter the relevant info (hostname, directory, userid/pwd) into a .config file or something.

Oh, and you probably need to have a database created on the host before you do this. Sites like dreamhost and pair have control panels where you create the database, and give the admin/dba userid/passwords. Then it comes back with the server host name/directory where you will point your config to.

Comment: BTW, this isn't a bug. It's a "RTFM" issue. And probably doesn't even belong on SO, should be on webmasters.stackexchange.com instead.